# how to implement edit option on table row itself with angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement EDIT option on Table row itself with AngularJS? can any one give suggestions

Comment: Do some research first and google around then come back and ask questions if you couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

First link on google when searching for "implement edit on row with angular js":
https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/